# Grunt htmlmin errors

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

I'm using `grunt-contrib-htmlmin` plugin. This is how my `Gruntfile.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true
        },
        files: {
          '/views/build/404.html': '/view/src/404.html'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlmin']);
};
```

Nothing special, really. My 404.html is also pretty simple, but even on simpler `HTML` files, grunt doesn't work. For example, let's say take following `HTML` file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't even work on that. What I get as a result in console is:

```
Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
Minified 0 files (1 failed)

Done, without errors.
```

Where can I see why it failed?

I tried really many things like removing `options` and I also tried changing `file` structure where I ended up with this:

```
files: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'views/src/',
    src: '404.html',
    build: 'views/build/404.html'
}
```

But that doesn't work either and error that I'm getting now is this:

```
Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
Warning: pattern.indexOf is not a function Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try with the leading slash removed from the path, so `'views/build/404.html': 'view/src/404.html'` instead of `'/views/build/404.html': '/view/src/404.html'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the actual reason for the error. But modifying the source by adding square brackes, as below, worked for me.

```
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'views/src/',
    src: '404.html',
    build: 'views/build/404.html'
}]
```

Comment: Yea, afterwards I did succeed to fix it, but forgot to answer here. I think I missed some of the mentioned properties.

Answer (score 1):

1. To see the logs run command:
   **grunt task:target --verbose**

   In your case it will be: *grunt htmlmin:dist --verbose*
2. The error seems to be in your file path: *'/views/build/404.html'*. '/' means that plugin will start to search from the root folder in unix systems. Use relative path:

   *'views/build/404.html': 'view/src/404.html'*

   OR

   *'./views/build/404.html': './view/src/404.html'*

P.S. For all others please note that in 'files' you should specify DESTINATION path first and only then SRC path.

```
 htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          /* options here*/
        },
        files: {
          'path/to/destination/folder/404.html': 'path/to/src/folder/404.html'
        }
      }
    }
```